# BPDUGuard and BPDUFilter on Spanning Tree Edge Port

Tags: cisco, spanning-tree

What is the difference between 2 ports configuration

```
interface Ethernet1/10
  switchport
  switchport access vlan 10
  spanning-tree port type edge
  spanning-tree bpduguard enable
  spanning-tree bpdufilter enable
```

and

```
interface Ethernet1/11
  switchport
  switchport access vlan 10
  spanning-tree port type edge
```

Comment: "Port type edge" just means that the interface is set up for STP portfast, which means that it will go immediately into a forwarding state rather than having to run through the usual listening and learning phases in canonical spanning tree.  It's good practice for end hosts.  BPDU guard is also good practice for end hosts, as the receipt of a BPDU suggests that either packets are being looped or there is another switch downstream.  BPDU filter is almost *never* a good idea, as it just silently drops BPDU's - thus inhibiting STP's ability to detect loops, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess I've found the right answer

Enabling BPDU Guard shuts down that interface if a BPDU is received. When configured at the interface level, BPDU Guard shuts the port down as soon as the port receives a BPDU, regardless of the port type configuration.

If the port configuration is not set to default BPDU Filtering, then the edge configuration will not affect BPDU Filtering. The port transmits at least 10 BPDUs. If this port receives any BPDUs, the port returns to the spanning tree normal port state and BPDU Filtering is disabled.